# Chinese Character in JSON code listing in LaTex returns errors

Tags: latex

I use the following LaTex codes to show JSON in the document:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=json,firstnumber=1]
{"src": "123", "dst": "345"}
\end{lstlisting}
```

It displays fine. However, when I change the values to Chinese characters, it shows 3 repeating errors:

- Improper alphabetic constant
- Missing number, treated as zero
- Missing = inserted for \ifnum

I have no clue what they are talking about.

[image: screenshots of error]

Additional Information:

Here are my related document headers:

```
\documentclass{sigchi}

\usepackage{balance}       % to better equalize the last page
\usepackage{graphics}      % for EPS, load graphicx instead 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % for umlauts and other diaeresis
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[pdflang={en-US},pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ccicons}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{eclipseStrings}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{eclipseKeywords}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{eclipseStrings}, % style of comment
    stringstyle=\color{eclipseKeywords}, % style of strings
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white}, %only if you like
    string=[s]{"}{"},
    comment=[l]{:\ "},
    morecomment=[l]{:"},
    literate=
        *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
         {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
         {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
         {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
         {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
         {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
         {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
         {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
         {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
         {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=json,firstnumber=1]
{"src": "中文字", "dst": "中文字"}
\end{lstlisting}

\underline{Example 1}
English: 中文字

\balance{}

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

p.s. I'm using Overleaf online LaTex editor.

Comment: Where is the `sigchi` document class? You should link to it, Google pulled up a few similar sounding ones, we cannot compile your document without a link to the `sigchi.cls` file. Also, are you compiling with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`/`xelatex`? `pdflatex` probably doesn't have support for those characters whereas the other 2 do, try and compile with them instead on Overleaf

Comment: @Raptor Can you please make a [mre] which allows us to reproduce the problem without having to edit the document first?

Comment: The `sigchi` document class is from Overleaf, can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/pjXVG3R7), compiled with `pdflatex`.

Comment: I tried to use `lualatex` to compile, more errors are found; then I tried `xelatex`, no error appeared, but the Chinese characters went missing.

Comment: @Raptor Your font probably does not have them and some of your packages/settings are not compatible with unicode engines like lualatex. Please add a compilable [mre] to your question which includes these Chinese characters.

Comment: my problem is, I can't even compile with common compilers... @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @Raptor We can probably fix this, but we need an example which does have your letters as text! It should be easy for you to type them - for non-Chinease speakers, that the difficult part of your question. Fixing the latex problem will be easy once you finally added these characters!

Comment: Understood, the code above is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with lualatex or xelatex, you could use the following code to choose a font which has the Chinese characters you use. An overview of the available fonts on Overleaf is available at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{sigchi}

\usepackage{balance}       % to better equalize the last page
\usepackage{graphics}      % for EPS, load graphicx instead 
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % for umlauts and other diaeresis
%\usepackage{txfonts}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[pdflang={en-US}
%,pdftex
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ccicons}
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{eclipseStrings}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{eclipseKeywords}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{eclipseStrings}, % style of comment
    stringstyle=\color{eclipseKeywords}, % style of strings
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white}, %only if you like
    string=[s]{"}{"},
    %comment=[l]{:\ "},
    %morecomment=[l]{:"},
    literate=
        *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
         {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
         {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
         {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
         {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
         {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
         {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
         {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
         {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
         {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=json,firstnumber=1]
{"src": "中文字", "dst": "中文字"}
\end{lstlisting}

\underline{Example 1}
English: 中文字

\balance


\end{document}
```

MWE on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/jzndwywmyngg

[image]

Comment: thanks. If I use `LuaLaTex` and `xeLaTex`, there will be an extra double quote at the end of the last Chinese string (as shown in your screenshot as well). Strange. Also, the colors are inconsistent. For syntax highlighting, the `dst` should be in purple color (same as `src`)

Comment: @Raptor That's because you also used `"` for comments

Comment: Thanks again. After changing the to `xeLaTex` and making the changes you specified, the JSON string can be shown without problem. However, all the Chinese characters on the same paper, in between `{CJK}` are no longer showing. The codes are updated above. p.s. I cannot access your Overleaf link

Comment: I wouldn't use xelatex. Lualatex is much more flexible and actively maintained.  For Chinese characters in normal text, choose a suitable `\setmainfont` from the list in the link in my question

Comment: Perfect! All texts work fine!